# Swiftui - How to select both category and subcategory from the picker and ForEach list?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I would like to select both category and subcategory from the list
Text to display category and subcategory names. For example,  Food: Dinner

However the picker is only displaying category and not subCategory List.

Following is the code :

```
import SwiftUI

struct Category: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let title: String 
let SubCategory: [String]?
    }

struct SelectionList: View {

@State private var categoryList:String = ""

let categories = [
Category(title: "Food", SubCategory: ["Lunch", "Dinner"]),
Category(title: "Bills", SubCategory: ['Utility Bill", "Telephone Bill"])
]

var body: some View {

VStack {

Text (categoryList)
Form {
Picker ("Category", selection: ScategoryList) {
ForEach (dategories) { category in
    Text (category.title).tag(category.title)
      }
   }
   }
      }
   }
  }
}
```

```
Text to display both the category and subcategory names when they are selected from the list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let us indent the text and correct the type errors.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Category: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String 
    let SubCategory: [String]?
}

struct SelectionList: View {

    @State private var categoryList: String = ""

    let categories = [
    Category(title: "Food", SubCategory: ["Lunch", "Dinner"]),
    Category(title: "Bills", SubCategory: ["Utility Bill", "Telephone Bill"])
    ]

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Text(categoryList)
            Form {
                Picker ("Category", selection: ScategoryList) {
                    ForEach (dategories) { category in
                        Text (category.title).tag(category.title)
                    }
                }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Second, the `Category` struct must conform to `Hashable`

```
struct Category: Identifiable, Hashable{
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String 
    let SubCategory: [String]?
}
```

And now change the `Picker` to

```
Menu("Category"){
    ForEach(categories, id: \.self){ category in
        Menu(category.title){
            ForEach(category.subCategory, id: \.self){ subCategory in
                Button(subCategory){
                    categoryList = "\(subCategory) in \(category)."
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mr Clearmutes . The picker selection is only displaying the category list and when I select one of the categories, it’s selecting all the subcategories linked to the particular category.
How to display the subcategories also along side of the category, and be able to select one of the subcategories. For example
Food:Lunch
Food: Dinner
Bills: Telephone Bill

Comment: I re wrote the answer. It now answers your question.

Comment: Thank You @Mr Clearmutes . With updated code I was able to select both category and subcategory! Appreciated!